# Pandas remove rows with only one type of value, repeated or not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove rows whose all values are the same, or a combination of the same values.

I have, for example a dataframe like:

```py
data = {'A': ['1, 1, 1', '1', '2', '3', '1'],
        'B': ['1', '1,1,1,1', '2', '4', '1'],
        'C': ['1, 1', '2', '3', '5', '1']}
```

I want to remove rows whose values in all columns are '1' or any combination of '1'.
The final result should be something like:

```py
data = {'A': ['1', '2', '3'],
        'B': ['1,1,1,1', '2', '4'],
        'C': ['2', '3', '5']}
```

I've tried the following:

```
def remove_rows_with_ones(value):
    return all(x == '1' for x in value.split(','))

mask = df.apply(lambda row: any(remove_rows_with_ones(val) for val in row), axis=1)
df_filtered = df[~mask]
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert to string and check if each cell contains a character other than `1` (or space/comma), if at least one True, keep the row:

```
out = df[df.apply(lambda s: s.astype(str).str.contains('[^1 ,]')).any(axis=1)]
```

Or, with your original idea of splitting the strings on `', '`:

```
import re

out = df[~df.applymap(lambda c: all(x=='1' for x in re.split(', *', c))).all(axis=1)]

# pandas ≥ 2.1
out = df[~df.map(lambda c: all(x=='1' for x in re.split(', *', c))).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   A        B  C
1  1  1,1,1,1  2
2  2        2  3
3  3        4  5
```

Intermediates:

```
# df.apply(lambda s: s.astype(str).str.contains('[^1 ,]'))
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False  False   True
2   True   True   True
3   True   True   True
4  False  False  False

# df.map(lambda c: all(x=='1' for x in re.split(', *', c)))
       A      B      C
0   True   True   True
1   True   True  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
4   True   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. If `item` in `all_same` is set to None, it will remove any rows where all cells only have one value, otherwise,  it will only remove rows where all cells only have "1"s.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': ['1, 1, 1', '1', '2', '3', '1'], 
        'B': ['1', '1,1,1,1', '2', '4', '1'], 
        'C': ['1, 1', '2', '3', '5', '1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def all_same(row, item='1'):
    cc = set()
    for val in row:  
        try:
            val = set(val.replace(" ", "").split(","))
        except AttributeError: # cell with non-string value!
            # decide if you want to ignore this, or reraise this
            # for simplicity I just `pass`
            pass
        cc.update(val)
    if item is not None:
        return cc == {item}
    return len(cc) == 1

df = df[~df.apply(all_same, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).